# Add toogle search form - navwalker - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4, font-awesome, wp-nav-walker

I want to add in my nav a loop icon (font awesome) and if i clck , the search input form display (toggle effect).

In function.php, i add this code :

```
function add_search_form($items, $args) {
if( $args->theme_location == 'header-menu' )
$items .= '<li class="search menu-item menu-item-type-custom dropdown menu-item-object-custom"><a class="search_icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a><div style="display:none;" class="searchform">'. get_search_form(false) .'</div></li>';
return $items;
}
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".search_icon").click(function () {
        $(".searchform").slideToggle();
    });

    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            //$(modal_or_menu_element).closeElement();
            $(".searchform").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.searchform {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-right: 3rem;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #343a40;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
.container { position:relative;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<li class="search menu-item menu-item-type-custom dropdown menu-item-object-custom">
<a class="search_icon">
<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
<div style="display:none;" class="searchform">
<!-- search -->
<form class="search" method="get" action="example.com" role="search">
        <input class="search-input" type="search" name="s" placeholder="Que cherchez-vous ?">
        <button class="search-submit" type="submit" role="button">Ok !</button>
    </form>
<!-- /search -->
    </div>
</li>
```

I use navwalker.
Before i don't use navwalker and this code works, but now, no action when i click on the icon.

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: We need to see the HTML that is generated by your navwalker, because this is what the JS and CSS operate on. Can you edit the question to include this please.

Comment: No not the URL, we need to see the HTML - you need to edit your question to include the generated HTML. Please see how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I put your code into a snippet and it works (apart from the HTML not being valid because it is only partial). There is something else that you haven't included that is causing the problem. You'll need to try to find that and then update your question so we can help with that part.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thank you. i forgot to add the js. It works

Comment: You forgot to include it in the question, or do you mean that you forgot to include the JS you gave us in your own code?

Comment: @FluffyKitten in my own code

Comment: Well that's one reason for a problem that I haven't come across on SO before! :)